# page accessible through transparent proxy in firefox, but not from a java post request

Tags: java, http, post, proxy, request

I'm trying to gather some data from [this website](http://bem.onec.dz), the problem is the site is only accepting requests coming from algerian IP adresses, and the only algerian based proxy that i found is transparent.

Now, when i set up this proxy in firefox, i am able to see the correct form, but when i try to request that page with the proxy set up from a java class, it gives me the "requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator" message.

Here's the code i use to connect to the page (the proxy's address and port are in the code for those who want to try by themselves):

```
private static final String RESULT_URL = "http://bem.onec.dz/index.php";
private static String PROXY_AD = "193.194.87.226";
private static int PROXY_PORT = 8080;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                    PROXY_AD, PROXY_PORT));
URL url = new URL(adress);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

/* posting the request and reading the response */
```

I also tried to set the proxy to the whole system, and same problem.

Comment: Actually, the page was filtering requests by testing the user-agent. Once i added a browser user-agent to my Java app, it could get the right response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to give the request a browser useragent instead of the default one, as the page used filtering based on that.